# How to get rid of scrollbars in firefox 8.01

Tags: firefox, scrollbars

I have a webpage that calls up a fancybox contact form. it works perfectly in Internet Expolorer .... perfect padding .. perfectly centered .. no problem.

In Firefox, however, the same form when called up has scrollbars both horizontally and vertically. Any size adjustment to the window produces the same result. Even if you remove ALL content ... its the same result.

Being relatively new I have search and found no solution to the problem and have tried EVERY available answer listed on the internet. what am I missing?  You can view a test page to see what I mean at http://www.e-scapez.com/test/test.html.

Comment: Which scrollbars are you referring to? Those of the parent window, or those of the iframe? Or both?

Comment: Those of the iframe only .... the parent window does not have scrollbars.